# Laravel get attribute from model depending on other attribute

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model with this attributes:

```
phone_number
mobile_number
mobile_number_24
display_phone
```

`display_phone` is a string which can contain either `"phone_number"`, `"mobile_number"` or `"mobile_number_24"`. I need to use that string to select one of the above. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
public function getPhone(){
    $which = $this->display_phone;

    switch ($which) {
        case 'phone_number':
            return $this->phone_number;
            break;            
        case 'mobile_number':
            return $this->mobile_number;
            break;
        case 'mobile_number_24':
            return $this->mobile_number_24;
            break;
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Something like

```
$this->get($this->display_phone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I find out, I had to use `$this->getAttribute($this->display_phone)`